# How to distinguish between single-row and multi-row multidimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a single-row Python multidimensional list:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

len(list1)
5
```

Here is a multi-row Python multidimensional list:

```
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

len(list2)
2
```

I would like to know that list1 is a 1-row list, but instead len returns the number of elements in the row, whereas with multiple rows len returns the number of rows.

How can I distinguish between a 1-row list and a multi-row list?

UPDATE:  for those who closed this question because it "was caused by a typo" please see my comment to the answer below.  My question was not the result of a typo and the solution is helpful.

Comment: `list2` is not a valid python list.

Comment: you are looking for: `list2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]` and then 
`len(list2)` will be `2`.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelSzczesny,  You are confused.  Did you mean `list2=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9.10]]?`. In Python, lists can contain anything: integers, strings, dictionaries, even others lists.  If list2 is as I indicated, it's a two element list, and each element is another list.    What, exactly, are you trying to figure out?

Comment: If this was an ordinary matrix, the dimension of list1 would be 1 x 5 and list2 would be 2 x 5.  If a Python list can't make that distinction then I need a different container.  But I wanted to see if there is any way to distinguish in this case.  Yes, list2 is a "nested list" where each "row" is another list.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny  - I was showing what list2 looks like, not how it was created.

Comment: It seems that you need to work through a tutorial on Python lists.  When you say `what list2 looks like` ... no, it doesn't.  "Looks like" is defined for every built-in type, with the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.  A nested list works the way you describe, but what you posted is *not* how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a native python way, but you could check the first element of a list to see if its another list and then dig deeper unless no new list type is found.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

def get_dimension(l):
    n = 1
    l = next(iter(l))
    while type(l) == list:
        l = next(iter(l))
        n += 1
    return n

print(get_dimension(list1))
# 1
print(get_dimension(list2))
# 2
```

Comment: Great -- you solved my problem.  If I check t1 = type(list1[0]) I see it's int, so I know it's not a multi-row list, and t2 = type(list2[0]) shows that it is a multi-row list because the type is list.  That's simple.

Comment: Exactly :) Glad I could help, happy coding!